# Meaning of 「どどめ色」

Tags: meaning, idioms

I came across this sentence:

> 「あんた ホントに **どどめ色**の青春を過ごしてるわね」

The context is that the addressee wanted to show the speaker a new move he learned by watching the same video over and over again.

Apparently 「**どどめ色**」 refers to a certain color (https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%A9%E3%82%81). I cannot really make sense of what it is supposed to mean here though. Are there any other examples of a color modifying 「青春」or are there any set phrases that help understanding the construction here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried Wikipedia?

> #### [どどめ色](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%A9%E3%82%81%E8%89%B2)
>
> どどめ色（ドドメ色、土留色）とは、その名前は知られているが正確な定義のない色。方言では桑の実、また青ざめた唇の色や、打撲などによる青アザの表現に用いられ、赤紫から青紫、黒紫を指す。
>
> 慣用句としては青紫色から「病的な」、不正確性から「不明瞭な」、泥色から「汚れた」といったネガティブな意味合いで用いられることが多い

Physically, this color refers to dark purple/blue, but ドドメ色(の) is more commonly used as an idiom that means something negative like "dark", "dirty" or "somber". Either way, ドドメ色 is an uncommon word mainly used in literary works, so if you used ドドメ色の青春 in an ordinary conversation, it would probably sound like a joke. (By the way, this word seems to have a sexual connotation in some dialects, but I'm not familiar with that.)